# display more than three items inside bootstrap 3 carousel

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to display a list of product by carousel the problem is It can't display more than three items in a row .What's the problem . Here is the code I use :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
        else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.left { left: -33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .active.right { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .next { left: 33.33%; }
.onebyone-carosel .prev { left: -33.33%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
.item:not(.prev) {visibility: visible;}
.item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
.carousel-control {
    width:5%
}
</style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
                     <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
                            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">

                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">5</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="Opitures/970767255465.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">6</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                             <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

                        <!--/carousel-inner-->
                    </div><!--/myCarousel-->
                </div><!--/well-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the code with browser , it group slides in a div with 'item' class and each item contains three slides .
This is the picture of the result :

[image]

How can I display more than that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 10000
 })
    
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
     //alert("slid");
 });
    
    
});
```

```css
.carousel-control {
  padding-top:10%;
  width:5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
         <h1>Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Slider</h1>

        <div class="well">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->
        </div>
        <!--/well-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this out may be it will help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look - [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/dkOtwuGb8y)

Change `interval: false` to for example `interval: 3000` to change slides automatically every 3 seconds.

3000 is number in miliseconds (3 seconds)

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for 7 items (max = 6); if you change max in JS you have to adapt CSS (100% / max);

JS:

```
var items = $('#myCarousel .item');  // collect all items
var max = items.length >= 7 ? 6 : items.length-1;  // max (also important for less than 7)


items.each(function(){
  var next = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if(i != 0)
      next[i] = next[i-1].next();
    else
      next[i] = $(this).next();

    if(!next[i].length)
      next[i] = $(this).parent().children(':first');

    next[i].children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)); // clone 'items content'
  }
});
```

SCSS:

```
.carousel-inner {
  .item {
    img {
      // width: 14%;
      width: calc(100% / 7);
      float: left;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    &.active {
      &.left {
        transform: translateX(-14%);
      }
      &.right {
        transform: translateX(14%);
      }
    }
    &.next {
      transform: translateX(14%)
    }
    &.prev {
      transform: translateX(-14%)
    }
    &.right,
    &.left {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }
}
```