# Adjusting number of items in bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/at606jpe/

I would like to write a carousel like the above fiddle. However, I am stuck at changing the number of items in the carousel.

Please help guys.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

Comment: What you mean by number of items? Number of items shown on screen at a time, or number of slides?

Comment: Please post your whole your code. One line is probably an mistake. At least I hope so. Also both these problems above has been solved numerous times on this server.

Comment: your question is not clear?

Comment: Number of items shown on screen at a time
Currently, it shows only 3 items
I would like to add more, or, dynamically according to screen finally

Comment: Use this one http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/ -- Bootstrap is not much suitable for your needs. I didn't much use Bootstrap carousel even when I used Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more items just add more divs with `class="item"`. For example:

```
<div class="item">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
</div>
```

Add as many of those as you want inside `<div class="carousel-inner">` and you will be good to go.

/Håkan

Comment: Currently, it shows only 3 items on screen at a time I would like to add more, or, dynamically according to screen size finally

Comment: ok. I misunderstood. Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795886/display-more-than-three-items-inside-bootstrap-3-carousel